# Reproduce pandas groupby method to apply it to a dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, multiprocessing

I've got a dictionary d that i want to 'groupby' on a specific key 'A' (which has duplicate values), to then create a dictionary of dictionary.

My input would be dictionary d :

```
d = { 'A' : [0, 0, 1, 1], 'B' : [1, 2, 4, 3], 'C' : [None, 0, None, 1] }
```

where d['A'], d['B'], d['C']... are lists of equal length (it really is equivalent to a dataframe, the order of element of the list is important).

My output would be a "2-layer" dictionary dd:
For every **unique** value v in d['A'], I would get the dictionary with every other key matching v.
For example:

```
dd[0] = {'B' : [1, 2], 'C' : [None, 0]}
dd[1] = {'B' : [4, 3], 'C' : [None, 1]}
```

I should also precise that list d['A'] is already in increasing order.

I've actually come up with my own method, but I'm wondering if I can optimize it (for example by using multiprocessing? My initial dictionary d has 36 keys, and each key could have about 10^6 values):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dict_groupby(d, key):

    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    # Group the values based on the specified key
    for i, v in enumerate(d[key]):
        grouped[v].append({d[k][i] for k in set(d.keys()) - set(key)})

output = dict(grouped)
return output

dd = dict_groupby(d, 'A')
print(dd)`
```

I then intend to compare it to this almost equivalent method using pandas (it actually returns a dict of dataframes) to see which one is faster :

```
#df dataframe equivalent to dictionary d
grouped = df.groupby('A')
dd = dict(chain(grouped))
print(dd)
```

Thank you!

Comment: are the values in A sorted? Your approach seems fair otherwise, you have to fix a few errors to have the exact output but the global logic is fine.

Comment: Yes it is sorted. I can see my mistakes now thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here would be my approach, this is a similar logic to yours but provides the correct output:

```
def dict_groupby(d, key):
    grouped = {}
    keys = set(d)-{key}
    for i, k in enumerate(d[key]):
        d2 = grouped.setdefault(k, {})
        for k2 in keys:
            d2.setdefault(k2, []).append(d[k2][i])
    return grouped

out = dict_groupby(d, 'A')
```

Output:

```
{0: {'B': [1, 2], 'C': [None, 0]}, 1: {'B': [4, 3], 'C': [None, 1]}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correction (and the new method setdefault I didn't know)